# File and folder not showing in HTDOCS folder

Tags: macos, finder

In HTDOCS folder, when I created a folder using php script, folder has creating successfully but it's doesn't appear, the folder is exist but it's just not showing, i know it because if i used spotlight search, it's appear and i can open it in different finder window based on click on spotlight search result. It's also happen when i copy some file, i know it because if I double paste those file, window confirmation ask me to replace or keep the file both. And this happen only in HTDOCS folder.

what is going here, i tried to show all hidden file but doesn't work. Can anybody help me on this?

So sorry im not native english speaker. I used OSX El capitan.

Comment: Is there a tutorial you are following or a set of instructions somewhere? I don't think El Capitan has an `htdocs` folder by default. Is the folder you are looking for actually called `htdocs` or is called something else?

Comment: It's actually htdocs. So, when we install xampp webserver, htdocs folder is document root for our web application and yes those folder isn't by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the Terminal and using the following command to unhide the folder:

`chflags nohidden PATH_TO_FOLDERNAME`

For example:

`chflags nohidden /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testfolder`